# Linux user permissions folder for multiple users

Tags: linux

I have to give user `jenkins` permission to `/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`. I can not do `chmod 777 -R /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` because the ssh keys are in `/home/ec2-user/.ssh`.
I tried using

```
setfacl -m u:jenkins:rwx /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

and I did not get any errors, but Jenkins still gets permission denied.

Comment: There is no coherence between the chmod and the location of your SSH keys.

Comment: Jenkins user needs to have access to all previous levels. Is it the case? 
Could you post the output of `ls -la  /home/ec2-user/` ?

Comment: To expand on @Kevin's comment - It needs to have `x` access to parent levels. Does it really need `w` permission there? Then you should probably `chown` to `jenkins` or use `chgrp` and use a group for that. `777` permission should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following function to check the access to all path elements.

```sh
pathex ()
{
  local p
  local a
  if [ -x "$1" ]
  then
    a=access
  else
    a='NO ACCESS'
  fi
  printf "%s: \t%s\n" "$a" "$1"
  p="$(dirname "$1")"
  if [ "$p" != "$1" ]
  then
    pathex "$p"
  fi
}
```

Esample usage:

```
$ pathex /var/log/syslog
NO ACCESS:      /var/log/syslog
access:         /var/log
access:         /var
access:         /
```